# Lack of payment processor blocking renewal reminders

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders, auto-renew

We do not (yet) have a Payment processor - Internet bank transfers (which count as offline payments) are more or less the norm in New Zealand.
However, we still need to set up scheduled reminders as memberships expire.
The lack of a payment processor means we can't select anything for Auto-renew options for each membership type, and this in turn is causing the form to create a membership reminder to fail, as there are no valid entries in the third part of the entity selector.
How can we work around this?

Richard

CiviCRM 4.4.4
[image: Screen shot of Sceduled reminder page]

Comment: The lack of a payment processor shouldn't affect your ability to use scheduled reminders.  Could you please a) update your question to indicate your CiviCRM version (plus CMS/version)?  Also, it's unclear to me what you mean by "there are no valid entries in the third part of the entity selector".  Could you please post a screenshot?

Comment: added to original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is because you must deselect the "auto renew options" text in the third input box. You can deselect with a Ctrl-click. I just tested on my 4.4.19 demo site and could save OK with that text deselected.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I didn't think that I had selected anything the first time I tried, but I must have inadvertently.